# To get Application ID for NFC based Identification System

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I am working on nfc based Identification System. I am storing data on android device and at the time of Identification The nfc reader reads the data from android device for this thing the android device should run in HOST based card emulation based on ISO/IEC 14443-3 and for the deployment the nfc reader send the Application ID to identify service as per Google Developer NFC documentation so how i get the application id for custom application

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html#SupportedProtocols):
"Specifically, Android 4.4 supports emulating cards that are based on the NFC-Forum ISO-DEP specification (based on ISO/IEC 14443-4)" So you cannot do ISO 14443-3 based HCE using this.

Comment: My mistake but how to get hold of that Application ID. That's my only question

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a proprietary application using HCE then it is up to you to create the AID used by the reader and registered by the app. You can choose any AID but see this [Setting up host card emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173181/setting-up-host-card-emulation?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer for more detail about how to choose the AID to avoid clashes with other apps.